# how can i make two form input are related cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to make this in my add.ctp.
when user choose the department, on the file form field, only shows the file with the same department that they choose

**in my add.ctp**

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('department', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Department', 'options' => array( 
                    'Administrator' => 'Administrator',
                    'Multimedia' => 'Multimedia', 
                    'Treasurer' => 'Treasurer',
                    'Marketing' => 'Marketing',
                ), 
                    'empty' => '(Choose Department)',));?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('fail_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'File','placeholder' => 'File Id', 'empty' => '(Choose File)'));?>
            </div>
```

**in my controller**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Borrow->create();
            $this->request->data['Borrow']['user_id']= $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Borrow->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The borrow has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The borrow could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Borrow->User->find('list');
    $fails = $this->Borrow->Fail->find('list');
    $fails = $this->Borrow->Fail->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'fails', 'fails'));
}
```

thanks for the kindness help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax post. after user select a department you should send an ajax post with the value of department and get the related files and update second combobox.

Comment: thanks for your kindness responds, but i'm new in cakephp. can you please help me how to implement the ajax post. i cant understand any tutorial on the web.